# Authenticate to SharePoint online inside our console application if we have SharePoint app-only permissions disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, authentication, app, pnp

On old created Office 365 tenants I use to authenticate to SharePoint online inside our C# console application using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
               
    string siteUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/CustomerServiceKB/";
    string clientId = "******";
    string clientSecret = "*****";
    using (ClientContext context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

But, as per my knowledge newly created Office 365 tenants has SharePoint app-only permissions disabled.

So will my above code fail to work if the SharePoint app-only permissions is disabled inside our newly created tenant?

**Edit**

now based on the reply i got from @Asad >> he linked me to this blog >> https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2021/07/07/app-only-authentication-in-sharepoint-online-using-latest-azure-sdk/ >> but this blog is using `PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager` which is based on this link @ https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline is deprecated as well... so how i can authenticate my .net core console application to SharePoint using non-deprecated approach? i feel that i will never get an answer ..

Comment: Did you register an app in new o365 tenant? Also, if you are not able to use this authentication method, you can check other authentication methods in [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/officedevpnp.core.authenticationmanager).

Comment: @GaneshSanap my code did not work.. and i think this is because in our tenant the `DisableCustomAppAuthentication` is set to Yes... i know that i can set it to false but i do not want to modify our tenant settings as we need to keep the setting most secured..

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you check my edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to check `DisableCustomAppAuthentication` property on your tenant. If it's set to True then your code will throw `Unauthorised error`.

Use below commands to enable authentication using client ID and client Secret.

```
Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false
```

Or alternatively, you can run this PnP commandlet:

```
Set-PnPTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false
```

Refer blog for more details: https://www.koskila.net/literally-breaking-changes-to-app-authentication-on-sharepoint-%F0%9F%98%B5/

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but i do not want to modify the tenant's settings by running this command `Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false` .. so my question is , how i can authenticate to SharePoint if i have `DisableCustomAppAuthentication` = true ?

Comment: You have option to use App Registration with Certificates. Have a look at my blog https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2021/07/07/app-only-authentication-in-sharepoint-online-using-latest-azure-sdk/

Comment: ok thanks i read your article. but will your approach work for console applications not hosted inside azure? as in our case our console application will be hosted inside a windows server 2019 and scheduled using windows task scheduler..

Comment: @johnGu It will work in Console App also. If you see the blog has code for .NetCore Console App as well.

Comment: so for the certificate how we can generate a certificate for our live environment ? as we should not used self-signed certificates on live in this correct?

Comment: Not sure if self signed certificates can't be used on Production environment. If the server admin is happy to create the certificate, then it's fine to use. 
If you are not having Azure to store certificate. Then store it somewhere is file system. This link has sample code (written in old deprecated Nuget packages) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

Comment: I am following the steps mentioned on this link @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread to register a new application inside Azure AD. but when i click to register a new application inside our azure account, i got this message

Comment: `Starting June 30th, 2020 we will no longer add any new features to Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) and Azure AD Graph. We will continue to provide technical support and security updates but we will no longer provide feature updates. Applications will need to be upgraded to Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) and Microsoft Graph.  Learn more` so is this approach deprecated?? thanks for your continuous help.

Comment: This should be something else. Creating an App Registration is not deprecated but a recommended approach.

Comment: so what is the message trying to say then? thanks

Comment: and from where i can find related code to authenticate my console application? now the issue is that your code uses `PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager` where based on my reading this nuget package is already deprecated @ https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline .. is my point valid?

Comment: I am not using SharePointPnPCoreOnline as it is deprecated. I am using latest cross platform PnP.Framework

Comment: so when you refer this class `PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager` this is using the non-deprecated PnP.Framework ? am i correct?

Comment: Yes, non deprecated. Everything I used is latest..

Comment: @johnGu  You have totally misunderstood the blog. PnP.Framework is NOT part of SharePointPnPCore. PnP.Framework and SharePointPnPCore are 2 different things.